# java put null in int variable

Tags: java, string, if-statement, int

I have a code

```
public int getValue()
{
    int i =  null;

if(condition)
{
i = 10;
}


    return i;
}
```

This works fine for String variables. How to do the same with int variables ?

Answer (score 5):

`int` is a primitive type. It cannot hold `null` value.

You can either use `Integer` to hold `null` values, or use `0` (or `-1`) as the default `int` value.

Comment: I guess -1 is more common, but after all it depends on what that int represents.

Answer (score 3):

`null` is a valid value for objects, not for primitives.

Since `String` instances are objects, this is why it compiles it this case.

To get your code compiling in the case with the `int`, just do:

```
int i;

if (condition) {
    i = 10;
} else {
    i = -1; //or some other value when the condition is not met.
}
```

Comment: You haven't really provided a solution to his problem.

Answer (score 2):

Only Objects can hold a `null`  value. Since int is a [`primitive type`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) it has its own default value.

Objects default is `null`

```
Data Type   Default Value (for fields)
byte                     0
short                    0
**int**                  0
long                     0L
float                    0.0f
double                   0.0d
char                     '\u0000'
**String (or any object)**  null
boolean false
```

Try

```
  int i =  0;
```

or even left it and assign later, If it is a instance member. Remember that local variables need to be initialize before they are using at that place you have to assign.

Answer (score 1):

The `null`equivalent for `int` is `0`.

Comment: This is wrong on so many levels. Integer null is the real equivalent.

Comment: Actually it really depends on the code - if you are searching for an index in a list you would like to return `-1` as the "nullable" value. But an unassigned int holds `0` by default, so would you care to elaborate more? Thank you ^^

Comment: int always holds a valid value, your application interprets it whatever it wants/needs, so there's no real equivalent for `null`. `i++` is ok on 0, -1... `o.someThing()` is not when `o` is null. There's a deep (conceptual and practical) difference! It reminds me of the "third state" of the three-state logic, but the analogy isn't perfect of course.

Answer (score 1):

You  can use `Integer` instead of `int` .

```
public static Integer getValue()
    {
     Integer i =  null;

     if(condition)
     {
       i = 10;
     }
        return (i==null)?0:i;
    }
```

If you don't want to change `int` , then you can give

```
public static int getValue()
        {
         int i=0;

         if(condition)
         {
           i = 10;
         }

            return i;
        }
```

Comment: You should also return an Integer, returning a null value with int as return type will cause some problems. Also, the second snippet will not compile.

Answer (score 1):

You can't put "null" as a value for primitive data type in java, but you can use Objects like "Integer":

Example:

```
public Integer getValue() {
     Integer i;
     return i = (condition ? null : 10);
}
```

The previous code will return null as Integer object if your condition is true, otherwise it will return 10.

But, commonly used to return -1 as default int value if conditions not matched, so you can use:

```
public int getValue() {
     int i = -1;
     return i = (condition ? -1 : 10);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I use a sentinel value like MIN_VALUE

```
public int getValue() {
    int i =  Integer.MIN_VALUE;

    // do something
    if (i == Integer.MIN_VALUE) {
        i = 10;
    }

    return i;
}
```

However the simpler solution is to give an appropriate default value like 10

```
public int getValue() {
    int i =  10;

    // do something

    return i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Primitives (`int`, `long`, `byte`, etc) doesn't have null values, that applies only to objects (and `String` is an object in Java). Also note that default value for primitives is usually `0`, for objects is `null`. You have several options to overcome this

Throw an exception

```
public int getValue() {
   if(condition) {
       return 10;
   }
   throw new IllegalStateException("Condition must be met");  
}
```

Or you can return some arbitrary number which will tell you that condition wasn't met, `-1` is a standard way.

```
public int getValue() {
    int value = -1;
    if(condition) {
        value = 10;
    }
    return value;
}
```

Also note that `i` is usually used within for loop, so I would prefer different name for that variable, it can be confusing otherwise.